# Effective data structure for overlapping spatial areas

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures, spatial

I'm writing a game where a large number of objects will have "area effects" over a region of a tiled 2D map.

Required features:

- Several of these area effects may overlap and affect the same tile
- It must be possible to very efficiently access the list of effects for any given tile
- The area effects can have arbitrary shapes but will usually be of the form "up to X tiles distance from the object causing the effect" where X is a small integer, typically 1-10
- The area effects will change frequently, e.g. as objects are moved to different locations on the map
- Maps could be potentially large (e.g. 1000*1000 tiles)

What data structure would work best for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing you really do have a lot of area effects happening simultaneously, and that they will have arbitrary shapes, I'd do it this way:

- when a new effect is created, it is
  stored in a global list of effects
  (not necessarily a global variable,
  just something that applies to the
  whole game or the current game-map)
- it calculates which tiles
  it affects, and stores a list of those tiles against the effect
- each of those tiles is
  notified of the new effect, and
  stores a reference back to it in a
  per-tile list (in C++ I'd use a
  std::vector for this, something with
  contiguous storage, not a linked
  list)
- ending an effect is handled by iterating through
  the interested tiles and removing references to it, before destroying it
- moving it, or changing its shape, is handled by removing
  the references as above, performing the change calculations,
  then re-attaching references in the tiles now affected
- you should also have a debug-only invariant check that iterates through
  your entire map and verifies that the list of tiles in the effect
  exactly matches the tiles in the map that reference it.

Comment: Thanks Kylotan - this seems like the most "comprehensive" approach to guarantee fast access. I think I may end up doing something like this but using a quadtree type approach for the per-tile storage, and maybe some type of clever cache for the per-tile lists to avoid lots of list duplication

Comment: I don't understand what benefit you get from the quad-tree: a tile map is typically (by definition) a 2D hash from position to tiles. You normally only need a quad-tree when you don't already have such a quick look-up system (eg. for continuous worlds, not tiled ones).

Answer (score 2):

Usually it depends on density of your map.

If you know that every tile (or major part of tiles) contains at least one effect you should use regular grid – simple 2D array of tiles.

If your map is feebly filled and there are a lot of empty tiles it make sense to use some [spatial indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_index) like quad-tree or R-tree or BSP-trees.

Comment: Good thoughts - I guess the map is probably about 10-20% covered with area effects so a spatial index type approach is probably better

Comment: A spatial index allows you not wasting memory for unused tiles. But note that most of such indexes are designed to store static data. As I understand in you case all "affects areas" can move along the map, so you will need to rebuild/update spatial index all the time. This may cause significant overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Usually [BSP-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSP_tree) (or [quadtrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) or [octrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree)).

Comment: What would you then put in the nodes to represent the area effects in a way that supports efficient query and update?

Answer (score 1):

Some brute force solutions that don't rely on fancy computer science:

1000 x 1000 isn't too large - just a meg. Computers have Gigs. You could have an 2d array. Each bit in the bytes could be a 'type of area'. The 'effected area' that's bigger could be another bit. If you have a reasonable amount of different types of areas you can still use a multi-byte bit mask. If that gets ridiculous you can make the array elements pointers to lists of overlapping area type objects. But then you lose efficiency.

You could also implement a sparse array - using a hashtable key'd off of the coords (e.g., key = 1000*x+y) - but this is many times slower.

If course if you don't mind coding the fancy computer science ways, they usually work much better!

Comment: There will be a large number of effect types so it'll probably have to be some kind of list. but then there is the potential issue that a single "up to 10 squares away" effect might require generating or updating 441 different lists....?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a known maximum range of each area effect, you could use a data structure of your choosing and store the actual sources, only, that's optimized for normal 2D Collision Testing.

Then, when checking for effects on a tile, simply check (collision detection style, optimized for your data structure) for all effect sources within the maximum range and then applying a defined test function (for example, if the area is a circle, check if the distance is less than a constant; if it's a square, check if the x and y distances are each within a constant).

If you have a small (<10) amount of effect "field" shapes, you can even do a unique collision detection for each effect field type, within their pre-computed maximum range.